# What is the preferred approach to a repeating task?

Tags: c#, multithreading, timer, task

I generally set up repeating tasks, like GUI updates, etc like this:

```
 MonitorTimer = new System.Threading.Timer(new TimerCallback(Monitor), null, 1000, 2000);
```

I have recently started starting tasks now with

```
           Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                MyApp();
            });
```

What is the preferred approach to creating a repeated task now? I can't see any obvious options to do this with StartNew.

Comment: What is a repeated task? When should it reach completion?

Answer (score 2):

I prefer to use Microsoft's Reactive Framework. Then I can do this:

```
var subscription =
    Observable
        .Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1.0))
        .ObserveOn(this) /* this is the current form */
        .Subscribe(() =>
        {
            MyApp();
        });
```

This handles all the UI thread marshalling, the timing, and the invocation of the method.

You can easily cancel it like this:

```
subscription.Dispose();
```

Comment: Is there any advantage using this over my Timer approach?

Comment: @ManInMoon - Yes, the UI-thread marshalling for one, but all of the linq and other operators that come with the Reactive Framework.

Answer (score 0):

Keep using System.Threading.Timer.  Alternatively, you can use Wait to wait for an event in a dedicated thread, but there are little good reasons for it I can think of.